# Cache Coherence and race condition

Tags: parallel-processing

As i understand  we use coherence protocols  to apply cache coherence in multiprocessor systems. The intention is that two clients must never see different values of the same shared data.
Then why should we worry about race condition?

Comment: Consistency often requires *multiple* locations to be updated in sync.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Race conditions can occur even if you don't use caches, so having perfectly coherent caches doesn't eliminate the need to worry about them.