# Cache Coherency vs writing to same element

Tags: multithreading, caching, memory, concurrency, race-condition

Following results are produced on Intel (haswell) x86_64. Assuming we have an integer array, int32_t A[32]={0}, consider the following function where func(&A[i]) is being called from two different threads.

```
void func(int32_t *elem) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) 
    *elem=*elem+1;
}
```

Assume **Thread1 calls func(&A[0])**, Consider following three scenarios for calling func on Thread2:

1. **Thread2 calls** **func(&A[16])**: There will be no
   issues as A[0] and A[16] reside on separate cache-lines, and final results is
   correct A[0]=10000, A[16]=10000
2. **Thread2 calls** **func(&A[1])**: There is
   performance hit due false sharing and A[0], A[1] residing on the same
   cache-line. However final results are correct A[0]=10000,A[1]=10000
3. **Thread2 calls** **func(&A[0])**: we're going to get wrong results due to a race condition, i.e. A[0]<20000

**Question:** since the cache-lines being addressed in the two threads are the same in scenarios 2 and 3, so why cache coherency protocol like MESI does not protect the results for scenario 3, whereas it's ensuring that results are correct for scenario 2.

Thanks

Comment: You need to precise the architecture as this is clearly architecture dependent. I guess your target is x86-64 processors isn't it? I may be also better to precise if you specifically target Intel/AMD/etc. processors and even the generation (things change since decades). The compiler may also be important.

Comment: Thanks Jerome, Indeed I'm looking into x86-64 and the tests I did was with Intel processor (Xeon E5-2695 v4), I did not know that generations could affect this as well, thanks for pointing that. I've added this info to the question. 
Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cache Coherence and race condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41199798/cache-coherence-and-race-condition)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cache coherency protocol doesn't protect for the scenario 3, because `*elem=*elem+1` is not atomic (at least it's not atomic in C/C++ [as described in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39393850/can-num-be-atomic-for-int-num)).

From [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_coherence) cache coherence guarantees:

> Reads/Writes to a single memory location must be seen by all processors in the same order.

But this is about individual operations. `*elem=*elem+1` contains two operations: read, then write.

Consider 2 threads doing `*elem=*elem+1` on different CPUs, and initial value of the elem1 is 0. Because each CPU is doing 2 operations, Read+Write, there might be sequencing as below. Let's mark each input-output operation with a real-world sequence number, so former occurs strictly before the latter:

```
CPU1                   CPU2  
---------------------------------------------
1) Read elem1 (0)
   Calculate 0+1                
                       2) Read elem1 (0)
                          Calculate 0+1
3) Write to elem1 0+1 
                       4) Write to elem1 0+1
```

Each cache sees Reads/Writes sequence in the same order as 1-2-3-4 (Read-Read-Write-Write), which is compliant with cache coherence, but there is still a race condition and result is still wrong (elem1==1 at the end).

If write down each step using [MESI protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESI_protocol), it also shows that both caches see Reads/Writes in the same order 1-2-3-4, but result is still wrong:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Renat, this is really great and putting into perspective the solution to my misconception of cache coherency vs register values being out of date.  Thank you